# How many different arrays can we get by replacing the two adjacent elements from the array with their sum?

Tags: arrays, dynamic-programming

We have an array `A` with `N` elements.
At any time, we can pick two adjacent elements of the array and replace them with their sum, thus getting a new array. We repeat the same operation as many times as we want.
My question is, how many different arrays can we get, by aplying this operation any number of times?

Comment: Is this homework?  What have you tried?

Comment: bruteforce, cannot figure out the state.

Comment: This is going to be dependent on the items of the array as well, do you just want the maximum possible number?

Comment: How many different arrays(not the same elements at the same position) can we get by applying our operation?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "different arrays", if your original array consists of N zeroes, you're going to get N different arrays, one of each length.

Comment: if we have 1,2,3 => possible arrays are 1,2,3; 3,3; 1,5; 6; - their count is 4; The case with 0,0,0 is 3, as you said below.

Comment: And if you have 0,0,0 => possible arrays are 0,0; 0, their count is 3 (counting the original array with 3 elements).

Comment: yes, some sub arrays, after applying this operation, happen to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that zeros and negatives are allowed? If only positive numbers are allowed, than result is simple :-)

If list has `n` elements, than there are `n-1` commas between pairs element pairs. Every new array is produced by changing some of commas with plus sing. With that we see there are `2^(n-1)` different arrays.

I think that with zeros it is possible to reduce problem to same sub-problem by working with left and right sub-arrays from zero(s). That is some recurrence, but I didn't figure it out yet :-/

With negative allowed it is much more complicated.